# Converting json data to select drop down options

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

This is my data being returned from ajax call (EDIT: json format now):

```
[{"PROCEDURE_ID":362183,"PROCEDURE_NAME":"Biopsy, Breast; Lumpectomy"}, {"PROCEDURE_ID":558975,"PROCEDURE_NAME":"Biopsy, Cervix"},{"PROCEDURE_ID":558977,"PROCEDURE_NAME":"Biopsy, intrauterine"},{"PROCEDURE_ID":558976,"PROCEDURE_NAME":"Biopsy, Libial"}]
```

I am trying to put this in a select drop down and no matter what I do, it fails, either select-options are undefined or jquery throw error.
This is what I have tried so far 2 different methods (selField is dynamic element)

```
success: function(json){

         if (json != '' )
            var vx='<option value="">All</option>';
               $.each (json.DATA, function(k, v){

                   vx+='<option value="'+k.Procedure_ID+'">'+v.Procedure_Name+'</option>';
               });
               $(selField).html(vx);
               }
```

Comment: Why not just return the data as JSON instead of WDDX? Adding `returnformat="json"` to remote CFC call will do that.

Comment: I tried that initially. But still found it difficult to put that as Options of the select box. The code inside success function was for that. And I also used $.each (res.DATA, function(k, v), it would throw jquery error. I am all game, I can change it to json format, but problem I am finding is to convert that data to select-options

Comment: Then you either have an issue with your jQuery code, or an error in your CF code.

Comment: Modified the question (Thanks Scott, guess json would be better to handle), now I am getting json format from CFC, but select option part still not working. Any suggestion what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, the data returned is all caps `PROCEDURE_ID` but your variables are not `Procedure_ID`. I bet the error is saying something about k.Procedure_ID not being defined.

Comment: You are also specifying the incorrect argument for `PROCEDURE_ID`. You should be using `v` instead of `k`. In your `each` iterator the first argument of the function `k` is the index, the second argument `v` is the element.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rshqy/) to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. That was just the typo (using k instead of v, I rely on key-value pair, but I tried everything used k too). But major thing was that JSON parse, which I think allowed it understand the string as proper JSON. It is working now. Thanks again.

Comment: You did not include all of your code but if you set the `dataType` of your AJAX call to `JSON` then it will parse it for you automatically (assuming that it is properly formatted json). [More on that here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289078/1636917)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong that I see from the code you posted. First, as Scott Stroz mentioned, you are referencing the JSON data in your `.each` loop using camel case but the JSON data actually has it in all UPPER case. JavaScript is case sensitive so that needs to match. Secondly, you are referencing `PROCEDURE_ID` using the wrong argument in your `.each` loop. The first argument of the function (`k` in your code) is the loop index. The second argument (`v` in your code) is the element data. So you need to reference both `PROCEDURE_ID` and `PROCEDURE_NAME` using the `v` argument like so:

```
vx+='<option value="'+v.PROCEDURE_ID+'">'+v.PROCEDURE_NAME+'</option>';
```

From the comments it also appears that you were not parsing the JSON response either. That would keep the `.each` loop from iterating. You can do so by using either `JSON.parse()` or by defining the `dataType` of your AJAX call to be `'json'` [assuming that it is properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5289078/1636917).

I created a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rshqy/) to show you how the `.each` iteration of your JSON object should work.