# how to return an array from php to ajax response in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays

how to return an array in php to ajax call,

ajax call :

```
$.post('get.php',function(data){
alert(data)

});
```

get.php

```
$arr_variable = array('033','23454')
echo  $arr_variable;
```

in the alert(data), it is displaying as Array (i.e only text), when i display data[0], 1st letter of Array i.e A is displaying.

Any suggestions ? where i have done wrong

Comment: use `echo json_encode($arr_variable)` this will convert your array into json format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use to encode the array like

```
$data['result'] = $arr_variable;
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

And in the success function try to get it like `parseJSON` like

```
$.post('get.php',function(data){
    var res = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(res.result)
});
```

Comment: is that enough, how to display in javascript, can i write a normal each loop to display array values?

Comment: Param#2 Should be a bitmask or a depth, not a bool., changed since, but cannot change vote.

Comment: @prassu I have updated my answer to be compatible with a dynamic amount of elements in the PHP array, after transmission it will alert each one, one by one.

Comment: @gautam3164 You don't need the $.parseJSON as the $.post will automatically trigger that if it detects valid JSON syntax.

Comment: @t3chguy no.you have to parse it when you are processing a json data

Comment: No you do not, if the dataType, which by default is auto, is set to JSON it will automatically parse it into a Javascript Array-Like Object.

Comment: Sometimes it is not triggered due to the JSON Syntax being incorrect or the response headers being malformed.

Comment: The dataType is not POST. The TYPE is Post. Read the doc before stating the wrong. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ `dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).`

Comment: ok cool...data is posted but data type will need to parse right.?so either you have to use $.postJSON() or in the success you have to use `parseJSON`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data

Comment: I think you can refer these..In fact we use parsing since the data will be returned in an normal format..like a json encoded string..you have to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `echo $arr_variable;` use `echo json_encode($arr_variable);` and then in `jQuery` you can access it like an object.

Once it is an object, you can access it as data[0] and so forth.

```
$.post('get.php',function(data){
    $.each(data, function(d, v){
        alert(v);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to display the array in javascript.. i need to display dynamically

Comment: Don't see the reason for the vote down but doesn't bother me overly.