# How to output json array value in ajax success?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have post the data and return the value with json_encode and get that in ajax success stage. but i can't out that data value in specific input. Here is my html input. The return value are show in console and alert box as below.

> {"status":"0","data":[{"user_id":"1","start_time":"00:00:00","end_time":"01:00:00","date_select":"2017-03-23","admin_flag":"0","interview_plan_staff_id":"1","interview_plan_staff_name":"Administrator","user_name":"\u304a\u306a\u307e\u30481"},{"user_id":"31","start_time":"00:00:00","end_time":"01:00:00","date_select":"2017-03-23","admin_flag":"0","interview_plan_staff_id":"1","interview_plan_staff_name":"Administrator","user_name":"uchida"}]}

```
<input type="text" id="admin_id" class="form-control">
```

Here is my ajax

```
function cal_click(cal_date){
   var calDate = cal_date
   var date_format = calDate.replace(/-/g, "/");
   var base_url = <?php base_url(); ?>
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Admin_top/getcal');?>",
    data: {calDate:calDate},
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(result){

            console.log(result);
            alert(result);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: console.log(result.data[0].user_id);

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You can access the results using `result.status` to get the status and `result.data`to get the users array. What else do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to get specific input from result

```
    function cal_click(cal_date){
       var calDate = cal_date
       var date_format = calDate.replace(/-/g, "/");
       var base_url = <?php base_url(); ?>
       $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Admin_top/getcal');?>",
        data: {calDate:calDate},
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result){

                console.log(result);
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                alert(obj.status);
                //alert(result);
                var user_id = [];
                var start_time = [];
                for (i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
                   user_id[i] = obj.data[i].user_id;
                   start_time[i] = obj.data[i].start_time;
                }
             alert(' First user '+user_id[0]+' Second User '+ user_id[1]+' First start_time '+start_time[0]+' Second start_time '+ start_time[1] );

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get data then use `alert(obj.data[0].end_time);` to get end_time in data array.

Comment: Yep bro, status is work but the data between [ ] bracket doesn't come out. :( please help me

Comment: I can't retrieve the "user_id" and any other inside data: . Please help me out bro.

Comment: use `alert(obj.data[0].user_id);` to get user_id inside data

Comment: Or you can use use `for` loop to get value in data

Comment: I can't get the user_id, it's say undefined. 

here is my updated json result. 

{"data":[{"user_id":"1","start_time":"00:00:00","end_time":"01:00:00","date_select":"2017-03-23","admin_flag":"0","interview_plan_staff_id":"1","interview_plan_staff_name":"Administrator","user_name":"\u304a\u306a\u307e\u30481"},{"user_id":"31","start_time":"00:00:00","end_time":"01:00:00","date_select":"2017-03-23","admin_flag":"0","interview_plan_staff_id":"1","interview_plan_staff_name":"Administrator","user_name":"uchida"}]}

Comment: I got it as your edited answer. Thanks you very much @Rafiq

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. How can i output that looping in each textbox in innerhtml?

Comment: You can use `$('admin_id').val(user_id[0]);`  to set value to   admin_id in the following html     `<input type="text" id="admin_id" class="form-control">`

Answer (score 0):

Use a each loop to get the ids,result is a object that has a data array:

```
$.each(result.data,function(i,v){
     console.log(v.user_id);
     //$('.admin_id').val(v.user_id);//use val to append the value, note you have multiple ids so you need multiple inputs 
});
```

if this doesn't work then you return a string not json so you need to convert it to json using:

```
var result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro but it's doesn't work both. :( I don't know why?

Comment: is your ajax successful?can you post a picture of your xhr request?

Comment: Yes bro, my ajax successful and i can alert that success result. Pls guide me how to post a picture in comment.

Comment: paste the link in the comment or update you question with the link

Comment: try something like: `var data = JSON.parse(result.data);var id = data.user_id;` and let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Read Following posts you will get idea about json parsing

[Parse JSON from JQuery.ajax success data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data)

[how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

and you can try looping like this

```
var parsedJson  =   $.parseJSON(json);
$(parsedJson).each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.status);
    $(element.data).each(function(k,v) {
        console.log(v.user_id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When in an AJAX callback, you can use `result.data` to access the array of objects being returned. You can work with these like you would any other Javascript object. You may need to deserialize the JSON first.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, the following code would do the trick, although it will only use the very first object in the array as you only have one text box.

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(result);
document.getElementById('admin_id').value = responseObj.data[0].user_id;
```

Comment: I did as u said, it's said like that - jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: In that case you probably need to parse the data using JSON.parse(result) as per some of the other answers first.