# WordPress hand posts from php to js with json_encode and post ID's to div

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I use to following lines of code to get the posts as an array and then send it back to the js which was asking for it by transfer the posts with json_encode to a JSON

```
function get_feedback() {
    if(isset($_POST['postId'])){
        $postId = $_POST['postId'];
    } 
    $cToken = get_post_meta($postId, 'cToken', true);
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category' => 'Feedback',
        'meta_key' => 'cToken',
        'meta_value' => $cToken
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($posts);
    wp_die();
}
```

I am then trying to post a list of all post id's to a div on my WordPressPage with following code

```
function getFeedback(postId){
    $(".show_company").hide();
    $(".show_feedback").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data:{
        action:'get_feedback', 
        postId: postId,
        },
        success:function(response) {
        $("#result").html(response);
        alert(response[0]);


        }
    });
}
```

But it is only messaging undefined.

the object passed from php to js looks like this if i show it plain:

```
[{"ID":387,"post_author":"9","post_date":"2018-05-17 23:06:35","post_date_gmt":"2018-05-17 23:06:35","post_content":"","post_title":"jitz - grad - 0106","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","post_password":"","post_name":"jitz-grad-0106","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2018-05-17 23:06:35","post_modified_gmt":"2018-05-17 23:06:35","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp\/jitz-grad-0106\/","menu_order":0,"post_type":"post","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"},{"ID":386,"post_author":"9","post_date":"2018-05-17 23:06:16","post_date_gmt":"2018-05-17 23:06:16","post_content":"","post_title":"hergott - 0001 - 4","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","post_password":"","post_name":"hergott-0001-4","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2018-05-17 23:06:16","post_modified_gmt":"2018-05-17 23:06:16","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp\/hergott-0001-4\/","menu_order":0,"post_type":"post","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"}]
```

So it is basically an object containing 2 objects which are posts. How do i address the attributes of the posts here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to parse the response as JSON, look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data) that adds `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call which forces jQuery to treat the response as a json object.  Note the comments mentioned where you may need to also set the correct Content-Type header on the server, for it to treat it as such.

[Parse JSON from JQuery.ajax success data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data)